# Azure File Share Download erorr 'Field not found: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand`1.CalculateMd5ForResponseStream'.'

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to download a file from an Azure FileShare. When I try to download the stream I get the error 'Field not found: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand`1.CalculateMd5ForResponseStream'.'
Here is my code. What am I doing wrong.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void GetFileFromAzureShare()
    {
        string connectionstring = @"...";
        //
        FSAzureFileShareStorage storage = new FSAzureFileShareStorage(connectionstring, "sftpfileshare");
        var s = storage.GetStream("OLD/Testfile_ignore.txt").Result;
        var text = new System.IO.StreamReader(s).ReadToEnd();

    }

public class FSAzureFileShareStorage 
{
    private readonly CloudFileShare _share;

    public FSAzureFileShareStorage(string connectionString, string shareName)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            _share = fileClient.GetShareReference(shareName);
            AccountConnected = _share != null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LastException = ex;
            AccountConnected = false;
        }
    }
      public async Task<Stream> GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        Stream rtn = null;
        try
        {
            if (_share.Exists())
            {
                var root = _share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
                var fileRef = root.GetFileReference(filePath);
                if (fileRef != null)
                {
                    rtn = await fileRef.OpenReadAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LastException = ex;
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had the wrong version of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement. Upgraded this to the current version and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved by yourself, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, if we want to download the file from Azure file share, we can use the following code:

```
/*
  install following sdk
  Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File -Version 11.1.1
  Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common -Version 11.1.1 

*/

 var connectionString = "";
            var filepath = @"D:\download\";
            var shareName = "test";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            var fileshare = fileClient.GetShareReference(shareName);
            if ( fileshare.Exists()) {

                var root = fileshare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
                var file = root.GetFileReference("keyCredentials.txt");
                if (file.Exists()) {
                    filepath = filepath + file.Name;
                    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
                    {

                        file.DownloadToStream(stream);

                    }



                }

            }
```

[image]